# How to execute a command specific to a file?

Tags: linux, vim

I have a file `read.html`, every time I paste something(e.g. from a webpage) into the file, I hope the original html format is also pasted along with the plain text. Here is a vim command that can achieve the goal,

```
set cb^=html
```

But when I paste something into other files, I don't want the html format attached, so every time I just want plain text, I have to execute this command,

```
set cb-=html
```

This could be very inconvenient, because I have to execute the two commands every now and then. So is there a method that could paste html format along with plain text when the current file is `read.html`, and only paste plain text when the current file is not `read.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use the `BufEnter` autocommand.

```
   autocmd BufEnter *  if (&ft ==# 'html') | set cb^=html | else | set cb-=html | endif
```

Comment: By the way, `cb+=html` should be modified as `cb^=html`.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use setlocal:

```
setlocal cb^=html
```

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#:setlocal

> Like ":set" but set only the value local to the
>               current buffer or window.  Not all options have a
>               local value.  If the option does not have a local
>               value the global value is set.
>               With the "all" argument: display local values for all
>               local options.

Comment: It doesn't work. I opened two buffers in vim: `test.py` and `read.html`, I executed the command `setlocal cb^=html` in `read.html`, it also affected `test.py`, when I pasted something into `test.py`, html content was also attached.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do would be to create a mapping that will toggle the the `html` option.

```
nnoremap <key> set <C-R>=(&clipboard =~# "html") ? 'clipboard-=html' : 'clipboard+=html'<CR><CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I decided to use a map,

```
nnoremap html :set cb^=html<CR>"+p:set cb-=html<CR>
```

So every time I want to paste html, I just need to type `html`, and it doesn't affect other files as well.